# Deleted content still in database?

Tags: 7, nodes

I recently went through a Drupal site I'm helping manage, doing a batch delete on a bunch of spam tickets through Administer > Content > Edit.

As it turns out, though, the data for this content seems to still be stored in the database, and is shown on our ticket list. Taking a look at a database dump taken after the deletion took place, confirms that they are in fact still present in the `node` and `node_revisions` tables.

Trying to access any of the tickets gives a "Page not found", and they're not listed in the "Edit Content"-list. Clearing the cache has been tried, and didn't resolve the issue.

In case it's useful, the node types are `ticket`.

Any insight into what has gone wrong and how to fix it would be most appreciated.

Comment: node_delete in the node.module calls

    db_query('DELETE FROM {node} WHERE nid = %d', $node->nid);
    db_query('DELETE FROM {node_revisions} WHERE nid = %d', $node->nid);

So this isn't a general Drupal problem. What's the node type or module of this nodes?

Comment: @BetaRide: The node type is `ticket`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that tickets posted by deleted users do not show up in the management interface, but did show up in our view.

Problem was resolved by changing the owner of the tickets to a dummy user, then deleting them through the management interface.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: As soon as 2 days have passed. :)